# Multiple forms on same page

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I use `FOSUserBundle` with `Symfony2`. By default FOSUserBundle profile edit and password change is on different pages, but I need these forms on one page and add one custom form. My idea is to override profile controller with additional forms, but maybe there is more easier way? I also had idea to post all forms in different controllers, but problem is that I need to show errors for any field and I don't think, that is good practice to save object in flash.

Answer (score 0):

I got a sidebar with the login and a few teaser on my page in my layout, so it's available from everywhere.

Just do the following in the twig.html file you want to use to display the login/registration etc

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block title %} Title {% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {% render controller("FOSUserBundle:Security:Login") %}
    {# Other Controller you want to render here #}
{% endblock %}
```

My login.twig.html file looks like this

```
{# app\Resources\FOSUserBunle\Security\views\login.twig.html #}   
{% block fos_user_content %}
        <div class="teaser-header">Login</div>
            <form role="form" action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">{{ 'MyLog Username'|trans }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username" name="_username" placeholder="Your Username" required="required" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">{{ 'Password'|trans }}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="_password" placeholder="Your Password" required="required" />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'Segel setzen'|trans }}" />
            </form>
    {% endblock %}
```